Instagram API with instagram login cannot publish container
Summary
We can create a media container successfully, but cannot check its status or publish it. Both operations fail with an error stating our application lacks the capability to make the API call.
Steps to Reproduce

Create a media container using /<IG_USER_ID>/media endpoint (succeeds).
Attempt to check status using /<CONTAINER_ID> endpoint (fails).
Attempt to publish media using /<IG_USER_ID>/media_publish endpoint (fails).
Wait for a period after container creation and attempt to publish without checking status (still fails).

Expected Behavior
After creating a container, we should be able to check its status and publish it.
Actual Behavior

Container creation succeeds, returning a valid ID.
Status check fails with:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
    "type": "IGApiException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "ADMy9Zm1p-X3NESP7EM5FXI"
  }
}


Publishing attempt fails with the same error, even when tried after waiting and without status check.

Environment

API Version: v20.0
Permissions: instagram_business_basic, instagram_business_content_publish
Account Type: Instagram Professional Account (owned by app owner)

Additional Information

App has necessary permissions.
Successfully creating containers suggests correct authentication and basic API access.
Error occurs specifically for status check and publishing.
Waiting after container creation and attempting to publish without status check results in the same error.

How to resolve this issue?
Steps to Reproduce

Create a media container using /<IG_USER_ID>/media endpoint (succeeds).
Attempt to check status using /<CONTAINER_ID> endpoint (fails).
Attempt to publish media using /<IG_USER_ID>/media_publish endpoint (fails).
Wait for a period after container creation and attempt to publish without checking status (still fails).


Facebook fixed this. Finally working now
